# Issue with naming variables after classes that are nested

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Why is it that the compiler gives an error for `Test Test` in `SomeClass`? The error reads **The Type 'TestNamespace.SomeClass' already contains a definition for 'Test'**

```cs
public partial class SomeClass
{
    //Error on the line below
    public Test Test { get; set; }

    public partial class Test { }
}

//In another file
public partial class SomeClass
{
    public partial class Test
    {
        private int someField;
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass
{
    //No compiler error here
    public SomeClass SomeClass { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SomeClass` has a property named `Test`, and a nested class named `Test`.  They are both members of `SomeClass`, and they have the same name.  This is not allowed.

Note: Methods in a class can share the same name, but not the same signature.  Technically, the signature *is* part of the name.

Comment: "Technically, the signature *is* part of the name." isn't that backwards?